# SCCM 2012 - PXE-M0F - abortpxe.com with unknown computers failing

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm, wds, sccm-2012

I have one SCCM 2012 server not correctly responding to PXE requests for unknown computers. The server has PXE boot support enabled, enabled unknown computer support, boot images available with OS deployments available and targeted at unknown computers. However every time a computer comes through I receive the following error.

*CLIENT MAC ADDR: 00 50 56 B9 78 87 GIUD: 4239B2EC-D505-4798-0F64-E19BF69BECF9
CLIENT IP: xx.xx.xx.140 MASK: 255.255.255.0 DHCP IP: XX.XX.XX.1
GATEWAY IP xx.xx.xx.1
Download WDSNBP...
Architecture: x64
WDSNBP started using DHCP Referral.
Contacting Server: xx.xx.yy.yy (Gateway: xx.xx.xx.1)
The details below show the information relating to the PXE boot request for this computer. Please provide these details to your Windows Deployment Services Administrator so that this request can be approved.
Pending Request ID: 4
Contacting Server: xx.xx.yy.yy
TFTF Download: smsboot\x64\abortpxe.com
PXE Boot aborted. Booting to next device...
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.
Operating System not found*

In this case the the computer is a VMware virtual machine (version 7, win 7 x64 architecture) and fails to get any distributions. Looking at SMSPXE.Log I saw the following

*Client boot action reply: 
    SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:06:58 PM  2528 (0x09E0)
Client Identity: 08279ae0-c184-4fa1-aeac-0fa25b4447fb   SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:06:58 PM  2528 (0x09E0)
Set enterpirse certificate in transport SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:06:59 PM  2528 (0x09E0)
Set media certificate in transport  SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:06:59 PM  2528 (0x09E0)
Set authenticator in transport  SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:06:59 PM  2528 (0x09E0)
Set authenticator in transport  SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:06:59 PM  2528 (0x09E0)
PXE::CBootImageManager::FindMatchingArchitectureBootImage   SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:06:59 PM  2528 (0x09E0)
PXE::CNotifyTimer::TimerSignalFunc  SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:10:22 PM  2696 (0x0A88)
PXE::CNotifyTimer::ProcessTimer SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:10:22 PM  2696 (0x0A88)
PXE::CBootImageManager::PerformMaintenenceTasks SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:10:22 PM  2696 (0x0A88)
PXE::CBootImageManager::PurgeOldImages  SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:10:22 PM  2696 (0x0A88)
PXE::CNotifyTimer::Init SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:10:22 PM  2696 (0x0A88)
PXE::CNotifyTimer::CancelTimer  SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:10:22 PM  2696 (0x0A88)
PXE::CNotifyTimer::RegisterTimeout  SMSPXE  15/03/2013 10:10:22 PM  2696 (0x0A88)*

For some reason the boot manager gets to FindMatchingArchitectureBootImage but then does nothing else, it doesn't provide any indication if it has or hasn't found a boot image. On all other errors I've looked at with people having problems with this step it shows further information about unable to find and then to return with abortpxe.com but mine isn't.

ItemKey="2046820353" is "x64 Unknown Computer" in my SCCM at the Primary site for this Secondary site Deployment server. I've deleted all the "Unknown" computers, I've cleared pending PXE deployments and updated Memberships of all relevant computer groups but it still won't work. Does anyone have any idea on where I should look to resolve this problem or to dig deeper?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I posted this I've come into the problem many times, and in nearly all of them it was Scope Options

Having any of the following options set caused problems, 60, 66, 67. In the case of only 60 being set it still allowed connection to an SCCM PXE point outside of the subnet with IP Helpers enabled but failed at providing a boot image.

In addition I've also seen incorrect vlan id's causing very similar issues. So in general if you get to the point that PXE starts, talks to CM but doesn't complete (and no error is reported), check your IP Helpers, your vLANs and your Scope options.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Network Card and create NEW, the same story in my site.
Maybe you found "Better" solution.